# Consolidating Inputs/Tags

Tags: input, input-fields, tags

Is there an etiquette to consolidating inputs/tags in a platform. For example:

15 people say they work at Washington, Adams and Jefferson in their profile and another 15 people title their work as Washington, Adams & Jefferson LLP

If the latter is correct and we would prefer all users to display the same title, is it safe to just merge the titles? Provide a notification of change? Provide the option to change? Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You got it right, if you need to standarize provide a heads up notification that the change will take place in x amount of time and then implement the change. And for future users whenever they input "Washington, Adams and Jefferson" you provide the correction/suggestion to use the option preferred.